# Why Does count() On A Sampled DataFrame Take Same Amount of Input?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When running a count() on a DataFrame (new_df) which is sampled at 1% of the original the input data seems to be the same (Stage id 40 & 41 below) as if I run the count() on the full dataset (Stage id 42 & 43 below).

```
df = spark.read.load("hdfs://spark-storage:9000/tmp/data.parquet", format="parquet")
df = df.union(df)
new_df = df.sample(False, 0.01)
new_df.count() # Stage id 40 & 41
df.count() # Stage if 42 & 43
```

Why is that, I though lazy optimisation would give much smaller data traffic on sampled data?

[image: Stage Monitoring]

Comment: Please clarify both dataframes creation. `df` contains doubled content of `data.parquet` file. But `new_df` due to given code is undefined.

Comment: Thanks, yes new_df is the result of the sampling. I have edited above. Not sure if relevant but the disk space of the dataset is about 5GB. I tried with smaller and larger datasets but the effect remains the same.

Comment: Ok, than I have edited my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case the main problem is that the `sample` method of the `DataFrame` class makes a full data scan. No matter how small is the fraction- all the data will be read.

Spark first scans all the data and then gets a fraction of them. So `count` action on subsampled data levelages this mechanism and needs enough resources to read all the data.

Comment: Thanks. I think that addresses my question. If you know a way to avoid that full scan that would be highly appreciated. I have data I really don't want to be fully scanned each time during the engineering phase.

Comment: I think for now there is no easy way to do it and solution would depend on task context. One way is using data partitions (if one exist), other- read only some files instead of reading all.